# How to open .fxml file in SceneBuilder

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I'm practicing javafx and I came accross this problem opening .fxml files in SceneBuilder.

The project I imported for study is from this repo on Github: https://github.com/Gleidson28/DashboardFx

I have also imported SceneBuilder to IntelliJ and can open some basic files with just javafx components but some other files just can't be opened. I guess that it's because of the components imported to the files from outside sources. Below is the error log and a screenshot:

```
java.io.IOException: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/D:/My_Documents/IntelliJ/company-spending-management-system/csms/src/com/gn/module/login/login.fxml

    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.load(FXOMLoader.java:101)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:91)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:108)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.updateFxomDocument(EditorController.java:2560)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.setFxmlTextAndLocation(EditorController.java:763)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.DocumentWindowController.loadFromFile(DocumentWindowController.java:389)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.performOpenFiles(SceneBuilderApp.java:668)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp$1.invalidated(SceneBuilderApp.java:520)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(Unknown Source)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.UserLibrary.lambda$updateFirstExplorationCompleted$7(UserLibrary.java:371)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/D:/My_Documents/IntelliJ/company-spending-management-system/csms/src/com/gn/module/login/login.fxml

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.load(FXOMLoader.java:96)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gn.GNAvatarView
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(Unknown Source)
    ... 27 more
```

[image]

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: well it writes, can't find `com.gn.GNAvatarView`. Just add (imort) all the packages used in the fxml files.

Comment: It's right at the first line in my code in the screenshot. So why does the log says class not found?

Comment: Copy all the JAR files from https://github.com/Gleidson28/DashboardFx/tree/master/lib and add them as dependencies to your project in IntelliJ.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with IntelliJ, I just want to open the files in SceneBuilder.

Comment: Did you add the jars to `SceneBuilder`? See if [this](https://newbedev.com/importing-jfoenix-library-to-scenebuilder-javafx) helps.

Comment: In the end, adding jars to SceneBuilder helps rather much. However Jfoenix jar just doesn't cooperate and that is why I'm still stuck. I had to remove all the components corresponding with it. Anw, that's enough for now. Many thanks for all your help. Wish ya all the best!